Enable authorization in Keycloak client using ClientModel
I am trying to create a client using the following code in my keycloak SPI. But i am not able to add the authorization for this client via code. Can any have any idea about how to add the authorization for this client using ClientModel (org.keycloak.models.ClientModel).
String privateClientName = "Test name";
ClientModel privateClientModel = realmModel.addClient(privateClientName);
privateClientModel.setProtocol(CLIENT_PROTOCOL);
privateClientModel.setClientId(privateClientName);
privateClientModel.addWebOrigin("*");
privateClientModel.addRedirectUri("*");

// Capability config
privateClientModel.setEnabled(true);
privateClientModel.setClientAuthenticatorType(KeycloakModelUtils.AUTH_TYPE_CLIENT_SECRET);
privateClientModel.setStandardFlowEnabled(true);
privateClientModel.setDirectAccessGrantsEnabled(true);
privateClientModel.setServiceAccountsEnabled(true);
privateClientModel.setImplicitFlowEnabled(false);

// Set the consent required setting
privateClientModel.setConsentRequired(false);

// client scope settings
privateClientModel.setFullScopeAllowed(true);

